# Robolectric is-singlepane(/single-fragment)-test

Tags: android, android-fragments, robolectric

I just started to try Robolectric and as I am currently playing around with the [Dynamic Single/Dualpane-Fragment example from the google developer page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) I thought integrating it there and doing some basic tests.

The first thing I wanted to test is *does the single/dualpane handling work correctly*.

So its basically down to:

- small device & portrait -> single-pane
- large device & langscape -> dual-pane

As the code for the example is online (and as it is a standard template in Android-Studio) I am not gonna copy it here again. Just one thing: On launch the activity determines if its single- or dual pane by checking:

```
 if (findViewById(R.id.exercise_detail_container) != null) [..]
```

**It seems that for Robolectric its always dualpane.**

So my singlepane test is pretty straight forward:

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)

public class SinglePaneTest {
    private ExerciseListActivity activity;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Before
    @Config(qualifiers = "port-small")
    public void setup() {
        this.activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(ExerciseListActivity.class).create().resume().get();
        this.fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    }
    @Test
    @Config(qualifiers = "port-small")
    public void testSinglePane() {
        assertNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.exercise_detail_container));
    }
}
```

**But the test fails.**

Can somebody tell me why? This should be working perfectly fine, shouldn't it?

Just for the record: Yep, in the emulator everything is working fine.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but should be small-port, as both android and robo documentation seem to suggest the order should be followed pretty strictly.

Comment: Yes, please read Weston's answer. But Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed with version 2.4 of robolectric!

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing order: `small-port` Don't know if will fix, but it is true that they must appear in the order in the table: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

> if you use multiple qualifiers for a resource directory, you must add them to the directory name in the order they are listed in the table.

[Robolectric example](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/annotation/Config.html) supports this ordering:

> Qualifiers for the resource resolution, such as "fr-normal-port-hdpi".

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't fix the issue. But thanks for the input

Comment: No prob, I'll keep it here so no-one else suggests it as solution.